# Multivariate Time series prediction with ImputeTS?

Tags: r, time-series, prediction, imputation, imputets

Is there any way I can use **imputeTS** for time series prediction with multiple regression variables? I am having blanks in y, a minute level data with NAs, while all my X(x1,x2,.. xn) are continuous variable ae without NAs

```
DateTime        Processed   Avg     1_Q   Median    3_Q

04/01/20 3:22       3       1.8      1      2       2.5
04/01/20 3:23       3       1.6      1      1       2
04/01/20 3:24       1       1.5      1      1       2
04/01/20 3:25       1       1.2      1      1       1
04/01/20 3:28       1       1.1      1      1       1
04/01/20 3:29       1       1.7      1      1.5     2.8
04/01/20 3:32       1       1.6      1      1       2
04/01/20 3:33       2       1.4      1      1       2
04/01/20 3:35       1       1.4      1      1       1.8
04/01/20 3:38               1.4      1      1       2
04/01/20 3:39       2       1.4      1      1       2
04/01/20 3:41               1.2      1      1       2
04/01/20 3:42               1.2      1      1       1.8
04/01/20 3:44       1       1.3      1      1       2
04/01/20 3:45       1       1.2      1      1       1
04/01/20 3:46       1       1.6      1      2       2
04/01/20 3:47       1       1.8      1      2       2
04/01/20 3:48               1.2      -      1       2
04/01/20 3:52               1.3      1      1       1.3
04/01/20 3:53       2       1.9      1      2       2
04/01/20 3:54       1       0.9      1      1       1
04/01/20 3:56       1       1.3      1      1       1
04/01/20 3:57       2       1.1      1      1       1
```

a complete data set can be find [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTNba3Was5MF8Vje0q0SxdUUwjoZtuG8WbBbIQ1avHy7T3Xza9KTgJTs0OUnbM5buBaR1Cjg4vPrf7K/pubhtml)

Answer (score 0):

**imputeTS** is really good for time series imputation (where you employ correlations of one variable in time)

In your case there is a lot of useful information in the other variables (inter-variable correlations). **imputeTS** performs univariate time series imputation, thus it only looks at each variable and it's correlation in time separately.

Since your variables `Avg`, `1_Q`, `Median`,`3_Q` seem to be highly correlated to `Processed` (where your missing data are) probably another package is a better choice. **missForest**, **imputeR** and other packages that employ inter-variable correlations (but not inter-time correlations) would be a better choice.

Might be, that you get even better results, if you come up with your own imputation routine for the missing data. The missing data always seems to be in `Processed` and `Avg`, `Median`, `3_Q` seem to be statistics about `Processed`. Maybe e.g. using always the `Avg` rounded to the nearest number as replacement for `Processed` is already quite good.